# Hibernate Session closings with Hadoop

Tags: hibernate, spring, hadoop

I'm an intermediate Hibernate user. I am trying to get some traction with Hadoop at my company. I'm using a library called spring-hadoop (https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-hadoop) to configure my application and inject my dependencies.

I'm having a lot of trouble getting Hadoop to respect my hibernate sessions. I'm hitting the legendary LazyInitializationException.

> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException:
>   could not initialize proxy - no
>   Session   at
>   org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:108)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:150)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.cglib.CGLIBLazyInitializer.invoke(CGLIBLazyInitializer.java:150)
>     at
>   p.model.ServicePoint$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$181013ec.getReadResolution()
>     at
>   p.service.ResourceService.getStartDate(ResourceService.java:77)

Resolution is a lazy init field on a ServicePoint object that is retrieved with hibernate in the first part of the map task.

The exception is thrown later on in the map task when I try to work with the ServicePoint object. It is not thrown in the reduce task. Modifying the ServicePoint hibernate mapping is not an option.

I've tried a bunch of approaches suggested by my giant "Java Persistencee with Hibernate" book such as:

1. Opening a session at the beginning of Map:

> Session session =
>   this.sessionFactory.openSession();
>   session.beginTransaction();

2. Adding stuff like this to my sessionFactory bean:

> prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">on_close < /prop>

Before i pull out all stops and try stuff like Conversation Interceptors, can anyone give me a suggestion ? Nothing works and the exception keeps coming.